# Change default location of new AVDs in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to change the default location where Android Studio creates AVDs to be the shared Users folder on a mac (multiple people will be using this machine),  This is my `/etc/profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/Shared/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/Users/Shared
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME=/Users/Shared/.android
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/Shared/.android/avd
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

However, everytime I go into Android Studio to create a new AVD, it always creates in `/Users/kroe761/.android`.  When I run `emulator -help-datadir`, I see this:

```
on this system, the default directory is 

    /Users/Shared/.android
```

So something is at least semi-correct.  What am I doing wrong?  Could it be that the command line is seeing the environment variables but Android Studio is not?

I know I likely have more than needed in `/etc/profile`, I've tried multiple things.

*edit: I have also tried this, which did not work:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/Shared/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/Users/Shared
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$ANDROID_AVD_HOME/avd
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

I am, however, still getting the same response from `emulator -help-datadir` with that configuration

Comment: https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/761-move-android-studio-avd-folder-to-a-new-location

Comment: Thank you, but I already have the variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` created, which is pointing to `/Users/Shared`.  Android Studio does not seem to be respecting that variable.

Comment: Hm alright, sorry about that. I'm not a mac user

Comment: No worries!  I appreciate the reply anyways.

Comment: have you tried accessing the AVD from another profile? Macs have profiles, so when you set `user/shared` and access it from a specific profile, it's going to append the user to the `user/shared` path. I would check another profile to see if it's getting set there too.